# Is declaring a generic getter typeguard method possible?

Tags: typescript, generics

Interface `Guard` has generic typeguard method `isExecutable`.

```
interface Guard {
  isExecutable<
    U extends States<this> | X,
  >(): this is Query<U> & Execute<U>
}
```

It is called like so:

```
declare let b: Guard;
if (b.isExecutable()) {}
```

I want to make `isExecutable` a getter, so that it is called like:

```
if (b.isExecutable) {}
```

Is it possible?

[Source Code](https://github.com/lusakasa/sqorn/blob/0ec3b0d3fe525fae1b0fc7a4142e1d734bb3908e/experiments/set-types-4/queries.d.ts#L117)

Comment: Nope, there is no syntax for property type guards. The only way you might get it to work is if you express your interface as a discriminated union instead

Comment: Thanks. Using a discriminated union of (every possible generic type) is not feasible in my situation. Guess I'm out of luck.

Comment: Probably not.. Might be fun to try though :)

Comment: The generic is the intersection of a subset of 9 types, making 512 distinct unions... that's fun for another day.

Comment: We can use conditional types to automatically create the union without having to write it explicitly, I would need to see the actual code though ..

Comment: Here's the code...

https://github.com/lusakasa/sqorn/blob/0ec3b0d3fe525fae1b0fc7a4142e1d734bb3908e/experiments/set-types-4/queries.d.ts#L117

Also, the 9 types are themselves generic on the union of 9 possible types...

Comment: FYI [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7150), closed as "by design"

Comment: Thanks. The method approach it is.